# Where is the full JID value when using xmpppy?

Tags: python, xmpp, xmpppy

Where do I find the full JID value after connecting and authenticating against a Jabber server when using the [xmpppy](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/) library?

I need the full JID for a subsequent `Iq` call to the server.  Specifying the bare JID (user@domain.com) results in the following error:

> If set, the 'from' attribute must be set to the user's full JID

I have read through the [online API](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/) and looked at some of the source code but still cannot find it.

The full JID looks like this: `user@domain.com/resource`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the non-underbar versions:

```
c = xmpp.client.Client(...)
# connect
jid = xmpp.JID(node=c.User, domain=c.Server, resource=c.Resource)
```

However, there is no need to set a from address.  The server will do this for you for all of the stanzas you send.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the JID being stored as such either, but in [auth's sources](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/xmpp.client-pysrc.html#Client.auth), line 213, I see

```
self._User,self._Password,self._Resource=user,password,resource
```

where `self` is the instance of `Client` we're authenticating; so maybe you could just recover this info and build yourself a [JID](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/xmpp.protocol.JID-class.html) from that?

Comment: @Alex that might work, let me try that.  Thanks for the trouble you took to answer this question.

Comment: @Philip, you're welcome, let us know how it works out for you!